# Indexing Error while File Handling with GridView in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-io, datagridview

I am trying to manage files and folders in a web site. I have tried to list folders in a listbox and files in current folder in another listbox.

I have decided to do it with datagridview. Finally I have found a sample for files and folders for listing only. Tutorial is here: https://web.archive.org/web/20210513005012/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/090110-1.aspx

I have added edit and delete columns to gridview.

filemanager.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvFiles" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    OnPageIndexChanging="gvFiles_PageIndexChanging"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="renFile" OnRowCommand="gvFiles_RowCommand"
    OnRowDataBound="gvFiles_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="delFile">
    <AlternatingRowStyle />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbFolderItem" CommandName="OpenFolder" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltlFileItem"></asp:Literal>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FileSystemType" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="FileSystemType" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastWriteTime" HeaderText="Last Modified" SortExpression="LastWriteTime" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Size" SortExpression="Size" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# DisplaySize((long?) Eval("Size")) %>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Rename" SelectText="Rename"
            ShowSelectButton="True" ButtonType="Link"/>
        <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Delete" DeleteText="Delete"
            ShowDeleteButton="True" ButtonType="Link" />
    </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

filemanager.aspx.cs

```
public void delFile(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
         //I have got error: 
         //System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 
         //Index was out of range. 
         //Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. 
        string filename = gvFiles.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString(); //on this line


        string path = Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["path"] + "/" + filename);
        //actually do not delete. Add a suffix in order not to list it to the user
        File.Move(filename, filename + "_del"); 

        PopulateGrid();
    }

    public void renFile(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
    {
         //I have got error: 
         //System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 
         //Index was out of range. 
         //Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
        string filename = gvFiles.DataKeys[e.NewSelectedIndex].Values[0].ToString(); //on this line

        string path = Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["path"] + "/" + filename);
        //just for experiment 
        File.Move(filename, filename + "_ren");

        PopulateGrid();
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of RowIndex at the line that fails?

Comment: @Steve I get error for all rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GridView [DataKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys(v=vs.110).aspx) array is available when you set the [DataKeyNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames(v=vs.110).aspx) in your markup.

It seems that you miss

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvFiles" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
.....
DataKeyNames="Name"
.....
/>
```

I am supposing that the column name is your unique key to work with.